# Forgot to add salt to rice before cooking. How can I add salt after cooking to fix that?

Tags: rice, salt

I cooked jasmine long grain rice - but forgot to add salt before cooking.

It is a small amount, about 250 ml dry rice.*

When the 20 min where over, I noticed I had forgotten the salt.

Adding salt by just scattering some crystalline salt on it gives a very irregular result.

I understand that salt is not needed for the cooking process itself - it is to be added for flavor.

**How can I add an adequate amount of salt to cooked rice?**

I think it is good enough to add salt to the surface of the cooked grains, and not necessarily to all grains. I would tolerate altered texture of the rice.

---

* In case the preparation details are relevant: I washed it, and added about 1.5 times water by volume. Heated to boiling, then heated minimally for 20 min covered.
(I fully expect that this method of preparation is unacceptable of other reasons than missing salt. This is outside the scope of this question.)

Comment: Note that the answer is not urgent for me - I crudely fixed it for now. But an answer may profit future readers.

Comment: There is no need to add salt while cooking rice; it is there for flavour. If you like the flavour, you can add it anytime. But try it without; you might like it.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Good point. But I already tried - did not work for me.

Comment: if you dont add it before the rice will be tasteless inside of the grain, so if you add it after you are just coating it with salt.

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid Yes, that's an interesting point. But I currently think that coating each grain individually is good enough. But when having lumps of several grains with no salt inside on the tong, it can be tasted. I think that is what happens when adding salt by a normal salt shaker.

Comment: Most of us I believe sprinkle salt on the item and stir or toss to evenly coat. Or am I on a different planet?

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid rice grains are not that large that it makes such a big difference. Unlike a quiche or a lasagna.

Answer (score 3):

Seems there is no need to cook rice with salt, at least in my country or my friends who love the culinary.
But if you really need some salty flavor in your rice, maybe you could:

1. Turn your rice into fried rice, seasoning in the end.
2. Make some yummy sauces and add onto your rice.
3. Dissolve salt in water to become a salty solution, spray it on your rice and reheat again.

Hope this would let your rice more flavored :P

Comment: Point 3. works pretty well - I had experimented with this: Worked at least ok even without reheating. I used a saturated salt solution, so it added not much water. (It may be even better with hot saturated salt solution, which is more concentrated.)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel nice~ Reheat will evaporate unnecessary water, let salt enter rice's texture and prevent rice become too moist, soggy and stuck on the container or pot.